# VMware copy a VM machine

Tags: vmware

I have VMware Workstation version 8 and I created a `VM` for `Win7 (name: W7_64)`.

I then tried to copy it to another directory, which did not work - it could not find the file `W7_64.vmdk`.

I assume that some files need to be updated to point to the right directory?

Answer (score 0):

As said above: [read the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), this is not a programming question, I will also vote for it to be moved.

If you want to clone your VM and have 2 instances of the same Win7 VM read [this article](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_clone_new_wizard.html).

If you just want to move/copy the vm to a different location, take in consideration the [official docs](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=1000936) that describe the process.